# Minimum and primary key in Single HQL

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jakarta-ee, hql

Can I get the minimum value for a column and associated primary key in HQL or using Hibernate/JPA Criteria?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

List items = session.createCriteria(Item.class)
     .setProjection(  Projections.min("col") )
     .list();